# mongoDB update does not work properly

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

With 'Insert' I'm totally okay with it.

PHP - MongoDB inserts way I wanted to but update does not work as I planned.

Right after 'Insert' the document which does not have "ip" and "time" fields.

'ip' field works totally fine - {'ip':'127.0.0.1'}

but somehow 'time' array field behaves strangely.

{'time':{'realtime':'2011-01-01 12:00:00', 'mongotime': ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00")}}

"time" should be inserted to the document and should be okay.

But both of this "time" array and independent 'realtime', 'mongotime' is inserted to the document.

As a result, I'm getting

{'time':{'realtime':'2011-01-01 12:00:00', 'mongotime': ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00")}, 'realtime':'2011-01-01 12:00:00', 'mongotime': ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00")}

I don't know why this happens...

This is so weird.

Here is my code:

```
$query = array('username'=>"$username");
$realtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$mongotime = new Mongodate(strtotime($realtime));
$set_item = array('ip'=>"$IP", 'time'=> array('realtime'=>"$realtime", 
         'mongotime'=>  $mongotime));
$db->member->update($query, array('$set' => $set_item));
```

Do I understand mongoDB in wrong way or does it behave improperly?

Comment: You've used this site enough to know that you can format code. Do that please. Just edit the question, highlight the parts that are code and click the code button in the toolbar.

Comment: I'm trying but somehow 4 spaces and 8 spaces indent does not work. Nvm. Now It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be OK.

As you developed your code you probably tested it a couple of times and updated the document with bad modifier documents. Now there's garbage in it.

Just test it with a clean document.